# Browse a menu with scroll down

Tags: scrolling

I would like your UX advices about a browse menu proposition :

[image: Interface]

Each entry of the top bar have many sub-entries placed at the left side menu. In this example, we have the "Publish" entry.
I proposed to browse the sub-entries of the left side menu with a scroll. Also the user can click for selecting another sub-entry (Generate, force update, live etc).

What could be pros and cons in UX?
How can I manage the behavior if I have sub-sub-entries of this menu left-side tree?

[image: sub-sub entries]

Comment: Thanks, It give me some ideas about tertiary navigation, I would like some advices about the use of scroll down for browsing the entries of secondary navigation (left side panel). It is for a SaaS platform.

Comment: Hi, there are several questions with this topic. Make a search using the top searching field. [Question 1](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/54584/115107), [question 2](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/54584/115107)...